# c# оптимизация кода (bitmap)

Tags: c#, bitmap, emgucv

Есть метод, который захватывает изображение с веб-камеры, находит лицо и рисует поверх него квадрат. Есть ли способ, как это можно оптимизировать?

```
    //при выборе камеры
    private void webCamChose()
    {
        if (webCamTextBox.Text != "" && choseCamera == true) //проверка, что камера выбрана
        {
            device = new VideoCaptureDevice(filter[webCamComboBox.Items.IndexOf(webCamTextBox.Text)].MonikerString); //получаю индекс камеры
            device.NewFrame += Device_NewFrame;
            device.Start();
        }
    }

    //обработка веб-камеры
    Image<Bgr, byte> grayImage;
    Rectangle[] rectangles;
    private void Device_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone(); //беру изображение с камеры и в bitmap
        grayImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bitmap);
        rectangles = cascadeClassifier.DetectMultiScale(grayImage, 1.4, 1, Size.Empty);
        foreach (Rectangle rectangle in rectangles) //для всех найденных лиц
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 5)) //цвет квадрата и ширина линий
                {
                    graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rectangle); //на каждом лице рисую квадрат
                }
            }
        }
        cameraPictureBox.Image = bitmap;
    }
```

Я прочитал в интернете, что BitMap очень прожорливая штука. Есть ли варианты, чем это можно заменить?

На данный момент загрузка ЦП доходит до 60-65%. Попытался обвешать всё using и это помогло, но крайне маленький прирост. Пробовал так же в конце метода писать GC.Collect(), но нагрузка только увеличивалась. При использовании Thread.Sleep(1) нагрузка так же уменьшалась, но крайне слабо (если поставить задержку 100, то более менее падает до 20, но картинка становится слишком дёрганной). Как вариант, можно попробовать уменьшить разрешение картинки, но из-за этого качество распознавания уменьшается.

Есть ли какие-то ещё альтернативные варианты, которые я не попробовал?

p.s. вот способ уменьшение разрешения, но качество распознавания, как я уже говорил, уменьшается сильно

```
        Size size = new Size(bitmap.Width / 2, bitmap.Height / 2);
        Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap, size);
```

(в дальнейшем использовать не bitmap, а newBitmap)

Comment: Нужно, по крайней мере, диспозить предыдущее склонированное изображение. `cameraPictureBox.Image?.Dispose();`

Comment: А нельзя ли не делать `Clone()`? Нельзя ли использовать то изображение, которое в `Frame`?

Comment: при использовании Dispose() крашит в Program.cs с System.ArgumentException: "Недопустимый параметр." (я ведь туда вставил....https://pastenow.ru/DI6U9 ? В самый конец метода, чтобы очистить)

Comment: Нужно поменять эти строки местами.

Comment: Всё, понял. Dispose чуть улучшило ситуацию. Попробовал без Clone и с ним - разницы практически нет (она, вроде, и есть, но это зависит от 13 планеты в 10 галактике. Запускаешь 1 раз - 1 результат, перезапускаешь и пробуешь ещё раз - другой. И они всегда разные...)

Comment: Вам не кажется, что нагрузку на себя берут не битмапы, а нейронка, которая распознает? Профилировать пробовали? Какая строчка кодал больше всего кушает времени? Ну ок, здесь можно new Pen вынести из метода, а то вы пересоздаете его каждый кадр, но сильно легче не станет. Зачем кстати вы клонируете изображение, без Clone никак? Ну и финально, запустите релизный билд и перепроверьте нагрузку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitmap не прожорливый, это тупо массив.
Проблема в отрисовке через Graphics, а именно в том, что этот класс рисует через GDI+ через чёрт знает какие вызовы в системе, вот и получаем нагрузку на проц.
Если хотите быструю отрисовку - рисуйте напрямую через WinAPI с помощью функции SetDIBitsToDevice

Если не хотите заморачиваться - есть библиотека RazorGDIPainter:
https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=razorgdipainter
https://habr.com/ru/post/164705/
https://habr.com/ru/post/164885/
https://habr.com/ru/post/165403/